# React Router Routes Don't work when deployed to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, react-router

Using Node/express/React with MySQL/Sequelize

I have a branch of my create react app app here: https://github.com/geochanto/nutrient-calculator-react/commits/edit-recipe

Which I'm deploying to Heroku here: https://nameless-temple-93876.herokuapp.com/

Locally both backend (expressjs) and frontend (React Router) routes work fine. **Problem:** on Heroku, while backend routes do work, only the root('/') react route works. Other routes just give a blank white page instead of loading respective components:

- https://nameless-temple-93876.herokuapp.com/recipes
- https://nameless-temple-93876.herokuapp.com/ingredients
- etc.

I tried a host of things, Mars build pack is one of them, but this instead gives an **nginx** error.

I also tried to manually set up static.json inside the client folder like this, but it didn't help:

```
{
"root": "build/",
"clean_urls": false,
"routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
}
```

}

This is my current config for the App.js:

**App.js**

```
const App = () =>
    <Container> 
        <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
            <div>
                <JumbotronComponent/>
                <NavBar />
                <Route path="/" component={Smoothie} />
                <Route exact path="/ingredients" component={Ingredients} />
                <Route exact path="/recipes" component={Recipes} />
                <Route path="/users/admin" component={Admin} />
                <Route path="/users/login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/users/profile" component={Profile} />
                <Route path="/image" component={Imguploader} /> 
            </div>
        </Router>
    </Container>

export default App;
```

Also have this in my main **server.js**

```
// Serve static content for the app from the "public" directory in the application directory.
// if production env, use build folder for static files
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}

// for local env, use /client/public folder
else {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/public')));
}

// server the client index.html file for all requests
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/public/index.html"));
});
```

Other relevant files:

- Express Routing: https://github.com/geochanto/nutrient-calculator-react/blob/edit-recipe/routes.js
- Routes Folder with specific route files: https://github.com/geochanto/nutrient-calculator-react/tree/edit-recipe/routes
- App js located here: https://github.com/geochanto/nutrient-calculator-react/blob/edit-recipe/client/src/Mainrouter.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question. Perhaps it will help someone else down the road:

I had a bug where I was serving the index file with **res.sendFile** from **/client/public** folder. Instead, on production environment I should have served it from **/client/build**, like so:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  app.get("/*", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
  });
}

else {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/public')));
  app.get("/*", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/public/index.html"));
  });
}
```