# React Routing not working on Heroku Deployment

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Full Stack React Application to Heroku but I am unable to load up other routes of my application.

My App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

// Pages
// =================

// Not Logged In
import SplashPage from './Pages/SplashPage';
import Login from './Pages/Login';
import Signup from './Pages/Signup';
import CohortSignup from './Pages/CohortSignup';

// Logged In 
import AdminHome from './Pages/AdminHome';
import InstructorHome from './Pages/InstructorHome';
import StudentHome from './Pages/StudentHome';
import Settings from './Pages/Settings';

import StudentProfile from './Components/StudentProfile';

// No Page
import NoPage from './Pages/NoPage';

// Components
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';

// Utils
import API from './Utils/API';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    // We want to change this state based on User Login Credentials
    user: '',
    userType: '',
    loggedIn: false
  }

   // class functions go here

  render() {

    // If the user state login is true, allow them to navigate these pages
    if (this.state.loggedIn === true) {
      return (
        <Router>
          <Navbar user={this.state.user} logout={this.logout} />
          <Switch>
            {this.state.userType === 'administrator' ? <Route path='/' exact component={() => <AdminHome user={this.state.user} />} /> : ''}
            {this.state.userType === 'instructor' ? <Route path='/' exact component={() => <InstructorHome user={this.state.user} />} /> : ''}

            {/* Path for student profile based on it */}
            <Route exact path='/student/:id' exact component={StudentProfile} />

            {this.state.userType === 'student' ? <Route path='/' exact component={() => <StudentHome user={this.state.user} />} /> : ''}
            <Route exact path='/settings' exact component={() => <Settings user={this.state.user} />} />
            <Route component={NoPage} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' exact component={SplashPage} />
            <Route exact path='/login' exact component={Login} />
            <Route exact path='/signup' exact component={Signup} />

            {/* Go to signup based on cohortID */}
            <Route exact path='/signup/:id' exact component={CohortSignup} />

            <Route component={NoPage} />

          </Switch>
        </Router>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

server.js

```js
// Allows us to place keys and sensitive info in hidden .env file
require("dotenv").config();

// Require Packages
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const db = require("./models");
const routes = require("./routes");
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session")
const path = require("path");

const MySQLStore = require("express-mysql-session")(session);

require("./config/passport")(passport)
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

let options = {};
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static("client/build"))
    options = {
        host: process.env.HOST,
        port: 3306,
        user: process.env.USER,
        password: process.env.PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB
    }
} else {
    options = {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'root',
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: 'tracker'
    }
}


// Options for mysql session store

let sessionStore = new MySQLStore(options);

// Pass in mysql session store
app.use(session({
    key: 'surfing_dogs',
    secret: 'surfing_dogs',
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.use(routes)


app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
    // res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'));
});


db.sequelize.sync({ force: false }).then(() => {
    let server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, function () {
        let port = server.address().port;
        console.log(`Server is listening on PORT ${port}`)
    })
})
```

Here is the [site link](http://www.gittrack.ml/)

The initial root page loads up fine but when I try to access the /login or /signup route directly from the address bar it does not work

Here is a link to the [Github Repository](https://github.com/dchicchon/GitTrack)

I have also looked at other Stack Overflow answers for my problem to no avail.

[React Routing works in local machine but not Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772411/react-routing-works-in-local-machine-but-not-heroku)
[React Router Routes Don't work when deployed to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51866714/react-router-routes-dont-work-when-deployed-to-heroku)

The solutions in these suggest that I add a static.json and have an app.get() method that will redirect any route to my index.html due to react being a single page application. If anyone could guide me in the right direction I would be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `static.json` file to your root folder (next to `packages.json`) with the following configuration.

```
{
  "root": "build/",
  "clean_urls": false,
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Would this go next to my server package.json or my client side package.json? My app is currently coupled and I am not sure where to place the static.json. I have tried placing it in both the root and in the client and neither work so far :(

Comment: @pythonNovice did you find a solution>